# Thumbnail of a Portion of an Image While Maintaining Aspect Ratio

Tags: html, css, image, thumbnails

I'm attempting to create thumbnails out of some images, each of which isn't necessarily the same size at the others.

Here is a **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scgCN/)** with my current code. I've read on some other sites, and even on here that I just need to set the width and height of the image class, then apply the overflow:hidden property, but that doesn't seem to be working. It's still changing the aspect ratio of the image. I know I could just simply remove either the height or width property, but I really just want to make a 100x100 crop of the image. I tried clip:rect() but couldn't figure out how to make it work. Ideally, I'd want to crop 100x100 from the center of the full-size image, but using clip, I don't think I can do this if the dimensions of my images aren't all the same.

```
.thumbnail {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    padding:10px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    border:10px solid #EEEEEE;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using css and html:

**First solution:**

**html:**

```
<div class="imageFrame">
    <img src="your_path" alt="thumb"  />
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.imageFrame {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    padding:10px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    border:10px solid #EEEEEE;
    position:relative;
}

.imageFrame img{
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    display: block;
}
```

**Second solution:**

here you will have to use some JS to add dynamically  the image url path to the `<div class="imageFrame"`.

**html**:

```
<div class="imageFrame" style="background-image: url('your_path');"></div>
```

**css**:

```
.imageFrame {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    padding:10px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    border:10px solid #EEEEEE;
    position:relative;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

Comment: Kind of does what I want it to. The divs are wanting to stack on top of each other, though.